# How do you sort a table with datetime by time with Ecto?

Tags: postgresql, sorting, datetime, elixir, ecto

I am hitting a wall at the moment. I am working with Elixir and Ecto and I have a table with data and a column with Datetime.

The Datetime column is as follows:

```
2017-11-16 16:02:01
2017-11-23 09:00:07
2017-11-27 13:19:58
2017-12-05 07:48:42
```

What I want to do is sort this table based on time, instead of date. So the result(ASC) would be:

```
2017-12-05 07:48:42
2017-11-23 09:00:07
2017-11-27 13:19:58
2017-11-16 16:02:01
```

Do you guys have any ideas in ecto? A postgres query might also help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I think something like this should work:

```
Post 
|> order_by([p], fragment("?::time", p.inserted_at)) 
|> Repo.all()
```

Here you use a fragment to in order to leverage the PostgreSQL casting mechanism which extracts the time part from the datetime. I have not tested it but I guess it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If the accepted answer won't work, try

```
from(p in Post, order_by: fragment("? DESC", p.inserted_at))
```